# create a button on product form in openerp

Tags: odoo

I am trying to create a button on product form. here is my xml

```
<record id="action_button" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
    <field name="condition">True</field>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="product_normal_form_view"/>
    <field eval="5" name="sequence"/>
    <field name="code">action=self.action_button(cr,uid, context)</field>                                                                                                       
</record>
```

=================

## button defined as

```
<group col="2" colspan="2">
    <button name="%(action_button)d" type="action"  string="Test Hello"/>
</group>
```

## in python file there is a method action_button

```
 def action_button(cr,uid,context):
        test={}
        modelname="Hello Usha"
        test['tryhello']=modelname
        return{'value':test}
```

=============

## on button click i get error, no attribute defined on temp_range for action_button

pl. help, thanks in advance

-Usha

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code and after modification it's working fine and the method is also executing.

```
    <record id="action_button" model="ir.actions.server">
        <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
        <field name="name">Testing</field>
        <field name="condition">True</field>
        <field name="state">code</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_product_product"/>
        <field eval="5" name="sequence"/>
        <field name="code">action=obj.action_button(context=context)</field>                                                                                                       
    </record>


def action_button(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    #your code
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: my textbox remains blank, it does not fill with "Hello Usha"

Comment: I don't understand why you are creating ir.actions.server. If you want to change the value of your field, just create a simple button and in .py method of button just call self.write() method.
In .xml file define your button like this:
<button name="action_button" type="object" string="Test Hello"/>
You do not need to define ir.actions.server
EX: return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'name': 'Usha'}, context=context)

Comment: I wanted to test button but in reality I need to convert an on_change to button click. I have several drop-downs on my product form. I have to form product name by chossing from drop downs. can you send your gmail/yahoo account ? are you working on openerp ?

Comment: @user1540295 yes I am working on openerp. you can call self.write() in your method which is called from button.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code::

```
<record id="action_button" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
    <field name="condition">True</field>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="product_normal_form_view"/>
    <field eval="5" name="sequence"/>
    <field name="code">action=self.pool.get('product.product').action_button(cr, uid,  context
    </field>
```

and make change also in py file where we the action_button method define

```
def action_button(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    test={}
    modelname="Hello usha"
    test['tryhello']=modelname
    return{'value':test}
```

Comment: text box remains blank. In reality I need to convert an on_change to button click. I have several drop-downs on my product form. I have to form product name by chossing from drop downs. can you send your gmail/yahoo account ? are you working on openerp ?

Comment: @BandishDavetext box remains blank. In reality I need to convert an on_change to button click. I have several drop-downs on my product form. I have to form product name by chossing from drop downs. can you send your gmail/yahoo account ? are you working on openerp ?

Comment: Yes I am working on openerp.and bandish09@gmail.com is my email id.